# How is Wave developed with GWT?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, google-wave

Whatever happens to Google Wave, its UI, in my opinion, is 'beautiful'.  In fact, it's listed as a real world project that utilizes GWT on GWT's web site.  I would like to learn how Wave was built using GWT, but there does not seem to be many documentation on that topic.

Could anyone please point me to the right direction with regards to documentation or show how that the Wave UI can be built using GWT.

Update: The question is how build the UI and not Wave itself.

Comment: AFAIR, Google Wave was built using an internal version of GWT, that had UiBinder, etc. much earlier then that official builds. So the code used some hacks to get things done - something which would probably not work with the GWT builds we are using. You should watch the related presentations on Google IO - IIRC, that's were they mentioned they needed to "clean up" the code they used to build Google Wave before it could be incorporated into mainstream builds.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen:  Your comment which points to the reference source code is actually the answer I'm looking for.  If you make that into an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse through the [reference source code](http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/source/browse/) and see how that's using GWT.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would check out [this site](http://www.waveprotocol.org/) that is built around the protocol that allows that sort of communication.  At that point, it's just a matter of implementing a pretty UI in GWT (that's a bit of a simplification, but the gist is the same -- the protocol is really the meat and potatoes of Wave).

Comment: The question is about how to build the UI, not the underlying Wave itself.